# Edit Django registration default templates

Tags: python, django

I am trying to override several of Django's default template's in the registration module but have had no luck.

My structure:

```
app
  -templates
    -registration
      -logout.html
  -base.html
```

My logout.html file looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>See you soon!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your help.

```
django 1.9.7
django-registration-redux 1.4
```

Comment: I do not know if the app sequence still matters in 1.9, but if you wish to override the admin pages registration templates, you need to put your app in the list of installed apps, *before* the admin. Loading templates goes according to which one it finds first in list of installed apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence in which your Installed Apps are listed affect which templates are loaded.

In your case, you wish your App's templates override that of Django's Admin, therefore, in the list of Installed Apps, put your app's name *before* that of Django Admin.

Comment: or put the templates into  a directory listed in `settings.TEMPLATES["DIRS"]`, like `BASE_DIR/"templates"`